# What methods exist to make composite charts in Excel; combining stacked area with a single line also?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, charts

Sometimes one might want to plot a stacked set of data but also have a column of data represented not in the stack but as a line running over the top of it.

Eg: like the black line representing "Demand" in this image showing energy generation sources (would be more obvious if I coloured it red but file not at hand).

I did this in Illustrator but the person I got the data from who uses Excel uses a kind of hacky trick of using negative values and representing that stack with outline and white fill, which make the impression of a line at the top of the last coloured stack (hard to explain briefly)> Anyhow that hack has very limited applications as it sin't actually drawing a line graph over the stacked graph data, so it cannot be styled as a line (dashed, red line etc).

[image: Me with AI]

here is is in Excel using that hack (not so good and using a different data set):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `Combo chart`.

Assign all series to a Stacked Area chart type except the one you want a line for which you will assign to a Line chart type

[image]